# java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create MD5 hash for file content

Tags: android, github, gradle

I'm trying to clone a project from Github and this error happened. Does anyone know how can I solve this issue? Here's the screenshot [image]

edit: Here are some of the errors. I cloned it using SSH. I also added SSH key from my personal PC.

```
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create MD5 hash for file content.
at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.hash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultFileHasher.hash(DefaultFileHasher.java:41)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.snapshot(CachingFileHasher.java:87)
at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.hash(CachingFileHasher.java:69)
at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:152)
at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readLocation$15(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:172)
at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readLocation$16(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:172)
at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess$StripedProducerGuard.guardByKey(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.lambda$readLocation$17(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:171)
at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.readLocation(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:171)
at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultFileSystemAccess.read(DefaultFileSystemAccess.java:79)
at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.cached(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.lambda$transformFiles$1(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:116)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:220)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:187)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:211)
at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.transformFiles(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:111)
at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.transform(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:79)
at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.defineScriptHandlerClassScope(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:156)
at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:76)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:117)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
```

Comment: Also would be helpful if you can include the error stack trace?

Comment: @AudwinOyong Apologies. Now updated

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps: [Data error (cyclic redundancy check)](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-data-error-cyclic-redundancy-check/).

It seems to be related to a file error.

Comment: Thanks! I already tried it but unfortunately, it still gives me an error